# Is there a more elegant way to compare timestamps without milliseconds?

Tags: sql, timestamp, firebird, datediff

I have a table AT_OBJECT with two TIMESTAMP nullable fields MODIFIED and CURR_MODIFIED. I need to compare them but milliseconds should not be counted. As of now I use SQL request:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  at_object o 
WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
    COALESCE(o.modified,      cast('01.01.2000 00:00:00.0000' as TIMESTAMP)), 
    COALESCE(o.curr_modified, cast('01.01.2000 00:00:00.0000' as TIMESTAMP))) > 0
```

It works but looks kind of ugly. Is there a better way to compare timestamps without milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like below to remove the milliseconds (actually convert all ms to zero)

```
DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date), date)
```

So

```
.
.
.
WHERE
   DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date1), date1) = DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, date2), date2)
```

And you could clean that all up by replacing it with a user defined function (hopefully my syntax is correct I don't have a Firebird installation here)

```
CREATE FUNCTION removeMs
(    
    @inDateTime
) 
RETURNS DateTime 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, @inDateTime), @inDateTime)
END
```

then nice and clean!

```
WHERE
   removeMs(date1) = removeMs(date2)
```

Edit: For Firebird the basic concept should work but the functions are slightly different

```
DATEPART -> EXTRACT(MILLISECOND FROM date1)
DATEADD -> DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1 * EXTRACT(MILLISECOND FROM date1), date1)
```

all of which can be cleaned up with a user defined function (hopefully my syntax is correct)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the milliseconds part at all (never in your software / queries) then the easiest solution would be to store the timestamps with appropriate precision, ie without millisecons. At the DDL it would be like:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  Foo TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL
);
```

Note the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)` - this takes care of the default value inserted by engine when user doesn't supply the value. If the field(s) are sometimes filled by the user then you also have to write `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` triggers which "delete" the milliseconds part from timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to timestamp and ignore milliseconds using date_trunc function. Refer below query.

This where clause worked for me.

```
date_trunc('seconds', "column name"::timestamp)= date_trunc( 'seconds', '2022-07-05 19:10:29'::timestamp)  ;
```